# How to remove square brackets from entire dataframe if not every row and column have square brackets?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have df that looks like this (with many more columns):

```
col1   col2    col3
[1]     4 
[2]     5      [6]
[3]
```

How do I remove all square brackets from the df if not every row and column have square brackets and the dataframe is too big to specify column by column ?

I can remove the brackets using this line of code, but the dataframe has to many columns:

```
df['col1].str.get(0)

df['col1].apply(lambda x: x.replace ('[','').replace(']','')
```

New df should look like this:

```
col1   col2    col3
  1     4 
  2     5       6
  3
```

Comment: `df.astype(str).replace({"\[":"", "\]":""}, regex=True).astype(float)`?

Comment: Take a look at [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your df to `str`, `replace` the brackets and then cast back to `float`:

```
df.astype(str).replace({"\[":"", "\]":""}, regex=True).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to apply your function to each cell, although you would want to be a bit careful about types. For example:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('[','').replace(']','') if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Produces:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    1   4.0  None
1    2   5.0     6
2    3   NaN  None
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case check `strip`

```
out = df.apply(lambda x : x.str.strip('[|]'))
```